# Google charts table random display

Tags: google-visualization

I have multiple tables in my app. In the app I cannot control the numbers of columns of the strings lengths in the column. Also I cannot control the numbers of columns of the orders of the columns.

Right now i have 4 tables in a set and one table in another set. I will put only the headers as the other data is confidential in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfaij.jpg) image. 
The problem I encounter is: since the string length in a column in the table is not the same as the same column in other table. The width of the columns are not the same within a table set. I have tried to check on page load the length of the columns but the tables is not drawn on page load. When i say a table set i refer a list of tables with same properties, same columns number and name.

I cannot set fixed size on a certain column because I am not able to know if for next table set how the columns distribution is.

How can I make all the columns to look alike? How can I catch event when the table is fully drawn?

Comment: you can use the [`'ready'` event](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#events) to know when a table has been drawn...

Comment: For some reason the ready did not work on the first place that's why I've wrote this questions. I manage somehow to make it work. thank you